# Integration of an equation containing Legendre Polynomials

Tags: integration, legendre-polynomials

Consider the Integration

$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2}P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx$

where, $P_{n+1}(x) ,P_{n-1}(x)$ are Legendre Polynomials

Applying integration by parts,we get
$x^{2}\int_{-1}^{+1}P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx -\int_{-1}^{+1}2x\int_{-1}^{+1}P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx$

(By taking $x^{2}$ as the first function)

Now, 
$\int_{-1}^{+1}P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx = 0$

So,$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2}P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx = 0$

But the actual answer is not zero, am i doing it wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Are you sure about this integration by parts ? Try with $n=1$.

Comment: Hint: To evaluate your integral, use $(2\ell+1)xP_\ell(x) = (\ell+1)P_{\ell+1}(x)+ \ell P_{\ell-1}(x)$.

Comment: @achillehui Ya i got the integration result using it, but i want to know whether there is something wrong with integration by parts

Comment: Your IBP is off, it should be something like

$$\require{cancel}\color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\left[ x^2 \int_{-1}^x P_{n+1}(t)P_{n-1}(t) dt \right]_{-1}^1}}}
- \int_{-1}^1 2x \left(\int_{-1}^\color{red}{x} P_{n+1}(t)P_{n-1}(t)dt\right) dx
$$

Comment: @achillehui Thank U :), So the inner integral is actually an indefinite integral and then we do a definite integral right?

Comment: yes, but that is a hard route to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial integration is not the way to go. Use the relationship
$$(2n+1)xP_n(x) = (n+1)P_{n+1}(x) + nP_{n-1}(x)$$
from which it follows that both
$$(2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x) = nP_n(x) + (n-1)P_{n-2}(x)$$
and
$$(2n+3)xP_{n+1}(x) = (n+2)P_{n+2}(x) + (n+1)P_n(x)$$
,thus
$$x^2P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x) = \frac{1}{(2n+3)(2n-1)}[(n+2)P_{n+2}(x) + (n+1)P_n(x)]\cdot[nP_n(x) + (n-1)P_{n-2}(x)]$$
and thus (remember orthogonality of different $P_n$  and $P_m$ ):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^1 x^2P_{n+1}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx& = \frac{n(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n-1)}\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)^2dx
\\ &= \frac{2n(n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+1)(2n-1)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}